# Android emulator cannot communicate with ngrok Flask API

Tags: android, react-native, expo

So I have a flask API that currently handles a Expo iOS buid. I went ahead and tried to do an android build, but I cannot seem to access my flask API with it. I am using ngrok to tunnel into my api and give me an ssl cert. (Expo requires an SSL cert to make any network calls, so that is why) I have tried using 10.0.2.2, and that works in the chrome web browser of the emulator, but does not work when trying to make network calls in expo. (For both the ngrok and 10.0.2.2 solutions, I get the error of [TypeError: Network request failed])

I have consulted with some other engineers who have a bit more exp than me, and I was given the solution to use [expo prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/) to fix the gradle properties.

````
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-localization",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0",
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "app.equimanager.equimanager-mobile",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "infoPlist": {
        "ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption": "NO"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "INTERNET"
      ],
    }```
Here is my current app.json file. I am ripping my hair out trying to figure this out, so any help would be beneficial
Thanks!

I tried ngrok, 10.0.2.2, and also attempted to try a proxy server, but nothing worked. I also used a  [json placeholder api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) to see if other calls work, and surely enough, this worked.
````